# Calcular a média de um grupo de resultados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um grupo de resultados e preciso calcular a média deles, como faço isso em jQuery?

Os elementos já estão em variaveis e separados por classes, exemplo:

```
deztotal = parseInt($this.find( ".dezmembros" ).html());
```

meu HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="setmembros" maxlength="3" name="setmembros"  value="10" disabled>
<input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="outmembros" maxlength="3" name="outmembros"  value="15" disabled>
<input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="novmembros" maxlength="3" name="novmembros"  value="15" disabled>
<input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="dezmembros" maxlength="3" name="dezmembros"  value="12" disabled>
```

Comment: O que está dentro do html? numeros? E quantos `.deztotal` pode haver? só um?

Comment: dentro do html está os valores do banco de dados mysql separados dentro de uma tabela por mês!

Comment: e são os meses do ano que vão gerar a média, são 12 campos para calcular a média!

Comment: Coloque o seu HTML e vai ter uma resposta, assim é dificil adivinhar como está o seu HTML.

Comment: coloquei o html!! ajuda ?

Comment: Some tudo e divida por 12, ué!

Comment: @bfavaretto é verdade, só somar tudo e dividir por 2!!! viajei!!!

Comment: Ops, seu HTML esta meio inconsistente.. alem de comprometer o uso do atributo `id` (precisa ser único), não está usando a mesma classe para todos os itens da média desejada.

Comment: O problema aí é que você deve usar jQuery.val() e não jQuery.html(). Se qusier que seja dinâmico (não apenas 12) divida pelo valor da propriedade **length**. apenas cuidando para não ser por zero. E Caso não seja possível mudar o HTML (que eu duvido) pode ao invés de buscar pela **class**, buscar pelo atributo **name**.

Comment: @PeterKrauss e Bruno Augusto, vou corrigir os erros, valew pelas respostas!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você já tem os valores em classes, o jQuery já devolve algo que se parece com uma array, com todas as ocorrências dessa classe... O método clássico para lidar com isso é o `.each()`,

```
var tot = 0;
var n = 0;
$('.m').each(function(){
   tot += parseInt( $(this).text() );
   n++;
});
var MEDIA = tot/n;
```

Todavia, para algo tão  simples quanto o cálculo de uma média, o ideal seria usar realmente uma array, e isso também é possível no jQuery, usando a função `makeArray()`,

```
var A = $.makeArray( $('.m') );
var Atot = 0;
for(i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    Atot += parseInt(A[i].innerHTML);
var Amedia = Atot/A.length;
```

Ver http://jsfiddle.net/P3MhH/

---

#### NOTAS

O Javascript não é era uma linguagem equipada com *map/reduce* para lidar elegantemente com *arrays*, mas hoje, mesmo com um [pequeno custo de performance](http://jsperf.com/speedy-summer-upper), já é possível fazer uso de funções de filtro e agregação das arrays. A média é um agregado típico, e pode ser expressa com esses recursos, veja [esse outro jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PY245/):

```
var A = $.makeArray( $('.m') ).map(function(a) {
    return parseInt(a.innerHTML)
}); // ou $('.m').map(function(){ return  parseInt($(this).html()) }).get();
var soma = A.reduce(function(a,b) {return a + b});
var media = soma / A.length;
```

Essa forma de expressar um algoritmo de arrays ainda é pouco usada, tem gente que acha ininteligivel, "coisa de matemático"... Tento evitar os preconceitos. Pode-se, por exemplo, [usar em especificações formais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25911/4186).

---

Quanto ao acesso aos valores de tags `<input>`, o mais fácil no jQuery é o `.val`... Para outras tags (tipicamente `<span>` como exemplifiquei no jsfiddle) o uso de nodeValue pode ser mais rápido, ver https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418270/287948

Comment: muito boa resposta!!! valew!!

Answer (score 2):

Apenas evidenciando [meu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25880/calcular-a-m%C3%A9dia-de-um-grupo-de-resultados#comment48029_25880) anterior numa resposta propriamente dita.

Existem dois pontos que precisam ser verificados para atingir seu objetivo.

O primeiro e mais importante é usar [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) pois você que pegar o valor do campo e não o HTML dentro dele (que sequer existe). Você até poderia usar [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), mas vamos martelar o prego e não parafusá-lo.

O segundo ponto é o seletor a ser usado. Você demonstrou estar usando a *class* dos elementos, mas usou uma *class* aplicada à apenas um único elemento. Mesmo que você corrija o ponto anteriormente citado, você só vai receber **12**, referente ao último campo, e não **52** como somatório esperado.

Infelizmente não existe uma forma nativa de se somar N campos automaticamente, então você vai ter de iterar. Tanto é verdade que até [plugins matemáticos](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/jquery.calculation.js) fazem assim.

**[Demo no Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/gnt6J/)**

Se, porventura, você não puder modificar o HTML (o que eu acho bastante improvável), você pode sim usar o mesmo HTML mal formulado, bastando alterar o seletor.

**[Demo no Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/gnt6J/1/)**

A idéia aqui é valer-se da habilidade de os [seletores](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) aceitarem alguns formatos especiais como que numa Expressão Regular.

Ao usar `input[name$=membros]` restringimo a rotina aos elementos cujo atributo **name** terminem com a expressão **membros**. Como todos eles terminam assim, mantemos o resultado **52**.