# Especificações formais, quando usar? Temos algum padrão de fato?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Quando especificamos algoritmos "simples" (trechos curtos de um sistema) para outros programadores desenvolverem, podemos adiantar algumas dicas sobre como implantaríamos, colocar ou tirar detalhes que possam ajudar ou atrapalhar na modularização ou generalização da solução, etc.

Sei que existem técnicas, ferramentas, liguagens e metodologias... Mas sei que a maioria requer cultura, padronização, e, sobretudo, uma certa familiaridade com Matemática por parte da equipe toda, coisa quase impossível de imaginar [no Brasil](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/noticia/2012/03/maioria-nao-sabe-matematica-ao-final-do-ensino-medio-segundo-saresp.html) (!). A pergunta é **"Qual técnica/metodologia/framework mais usado hoje para se especificar algoritmos críticos?"**

---

---

## NOTAS

A burocracia (de uma especificação um pouco mais formal) tem um preço, mas estou supondo que desejo pagar esse preço por demandar alta [confiabilidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_engineering) (ex. aplicações bancárias ou hospitalares) e/ou *performance* (ex. dispositivos móveis ou de tempo real) do resultado.

Naturalmente, surgirão sub-perguntas (exemplos),

- "Em qual nível de detalhe devo parar?";
- "Devo usar uma segunda linguagem, de mais alto nível, para especificar?";
- "O Javascript se presta como linguagem de especificação hoje? Posso usar conceitos avançados, como *map/reduce* nas especificações que todo mundo vai entender?"

---

Existe todo um ramo da *Engenharia de software* para sugerir métodos apropriados para se "expressar o que queremos para outros programadores"... E uma parte desse ramo é a chamada [teoria das especificações formais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_specification). Existem métodologias que partem de diagramas [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) até chegar num *stub* da classe, método ou função... Mas o foco nesta pergunta é realmente o algoritmo, as dicas de como ele funciona ou como ele deve responder às entradas.

Todas essas considerações são teóricas e vagas, acho que todos precisamos de respostas mais práticas e objetivas para decisões no dia-a-dia com uma equipe de desenvolvedores mediana (sem formação matemática).

### Contexto

[Este jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C5qF/) mostra meus experimentos com `jQuery.makeArray()`, as funções nativas `map()` e `reduce()`, e quando eles são mais elegantes que um loop `each()` ou `for` comum... Tem um contexto HTML, etc. e até uma  ([pergunta real](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25880/4186) associada),  de modo que podemos usar de exemplo de caso.

### Subsídios para as respostas e discussões

Para usar mais objetivamente o **[jsFiddle citado](http://jsfiddle.net/2C5qF/)**, imaginemos que quero especificar a média dos itens do texto de uma página HTML.

A especificação pode ter vários níveis, desde texto livre até modelos matemáticos...

- *Nivel-1* (texto livre): mostrar em bold a média dos itens vermelhos.
- *Nivel-2* (texto técnico focado no HTML): mostrar a média dos itens de `class="m"` num parágrafo abaixo, em bold.
- *Nivel-3* (texto técnico supondo equipe jQuery e layout prefixado): fazer a média dos itens `$('.m')` supondo números inteiros, colocando o resultado em `$('#r1').html()`.
- *Nivel-...*: criar rotina para fazer a média dos valores de `$.makeArray($('.m')).map(function(a){return parseInt(a.innerHTML)})` ...
- *Nivel-N*: criar rotina simples (leve), altamente confiável e de máxima performance; para fazer a média dos valores de `A=$.makeArray($('.m')).map(function(a){return parseInt(a.innerHTML)})`, ou seja, `A.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;})/A.length`. Colocar o resultado em  `$('#r1').html()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre trabalhei em empresas do setor financeiro, embora a natureza dos sistemas varie bastante.

Em minha experiência prática, vejo ser quase impossível definir um modelo geral de especificação que atenda a todos os casos, seja ele formal ou não.

Por exemplo, em um sistema de contabilidade, um modelo matemático iria mais confundir que ajudar a especificar as partes críticas do sistema. No entanto, o desenvolvedor precisa de um treinamento básico para entender as fórmulas e o processo de contabilidade. A especificação e os exemplos muitas vezes são feitos usando planilhas, que muitos contadores tem familiaridade, sendo então possível interagir numa "linguagem comum".

Já em sistemas cujos requisitos sejam oriundos de legislação, há geralmente imprecisão ou sobreposição no entendimento das leis envolvidas. Então o que geralmente se faz é definir alguns casos possíveis e especificá-los usando dados de entrada como exemplo e exemplificando a saída. De qualquer forma, o desenvolvedor terá que ter um entendimento mínimo da legislação para verificar se o que ele está implementando faz sentido.

Para regras de negócio em geral, vejo muitos analistas simplesmente escreverem um documento de texto com o "algoritmo" em modo descritivo. Isso funciona, mas o desenvolvedor precisa transformar esse entendimento em código, tendo então que dominar a tecnologia.

Alguns analistas técnicas chegam ao ponto de especificar detalhes de implementação. Isso é bom se os desenvolvedores forem iniciantes, mas por outro lado "amarra" a implementação e geralmente não gera uma solução ótima.

Um princípio extraído de todas as observações acima, de muita leitura e da experiência prática é que os desenvolvedores precisam ser tecnicamente capacitados para escrever código de qualidade e, ao mesmo tempo, entender bem o objeto daquilo que está fazendo.

Outro princípio é que cada área de conhecimento já deve possuir seus meios de especificação adequados.

Na prática, uma boa especificação **não** garante uma correta implementação, até porque a maioria dos *bugs* não são intencionais. Documentação *nunca* irá substituir bons profissionais. Aliás, nada substitui bons profissionais de TI tralhando lado a lado com o pessoal da área de negócios entendendo aquilo que eles fazem.